# submit button to redirect to another link

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to mimic a Google Search page to learn HTML5. What I want is when the user types in the text button, and then click `submit`, users will be directed to google search results. When users click the button `I'm feeling lucky`, users will be directed to a link I defined before. However, after writing the code, users will be directed to a google search page no matter what buttons they click. Could anyone help me to figure out why?

```
     <form action="https://google.com/search">
        <div>
            <center><input class = "search_bar" type="text" name="q"></center>
        </div>

        <div class = "search_button_container">
            <input class = "search_button" type="submit" value="Google Search">
            &nbsp
            <a href="https://www.google.com/logos/lem/">
            <button class="search_button">I'm feeling lucky</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type="submit"` is causing the issue. Even if you dont give `type="submit"`, [by default](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) the button type is `submit`. So your form submits to the action url.

Change `type="submit"`  to `type="button"` in your *I am feeling lucky* button.